# Android OpenGL lighting depends on face size

Tags: android, opengl-es, lighting

I'm currently working on some opengl 2D stuff. I have a spot light which reaches two faces with different width and height. somehow the light gradient on the faces depends on their size. how can I make the gradient be independant from the faces size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without images its hard to say what your exact problem is but the most liekly issue is that the lighting is evaluated at the vertices and then interpolated across the triangles.  Different sized tris will give different interpolations.  This becomes more of a problem in the fall off at the edge of the range of a light.

If you want a more accurate lighting model then you will probably need to break out the fragment shaders and do per-pixel/fragment lighting instead.

Comment: how to enable per-pixel lighting?

Comment: @Zolex:  You don't enable it, you develop it. http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/glsl/5_lighting_perpixel.html

Comment: i guess this is not possible with opengl es 1.0 ?!

Comment: @Zolex: It can be done with directional lighting and GL_DOT3_RGB (amongst other methods) ... but per-pixel lighting without shaders will always be difficult ... its definitely doable.  You can get all sorts of interesting lighting effects if you understand the texture cascade properly, but it would be more than a long post to explain in a generalised fashion.

Comment: ok, tanks anyway, but I decided to omit lighting for this project. next one will be using gles20

Comment: @Zolex: Sorry I can't be more help.  I've thought many times of writing a blog post explaining how to do per-pixel lighting using the texture cascade but everytime I sit down and start I remember that fixed function rendering is used by next to noone these days.  It seems too much effort to write a huge document for something noone will ever use ;)